# Why doesn't this pointer get the value at the array index?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int func(int arg0, int *arg1, int *arg2);

int main() {
    int *b;
    int z;
    int a[10];

    z = func(*a[0], &a[z], b+a[4]);
}
```

The following code above gives me an error "invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')". I know that `*` when used in a declaration creates a pointer and when used with a variable name it gets the value stored at that pointer. In the function `func()`, it takes 3 parameters, 1 int and 2 int pointers. I think that the first argument passed into the function is giving me an error but I am not understanding why. Shouldn't `*a[0]` get the value of the first element in the `a` array which was declared as an int?

Comment: `*` isn't a unary operator to `int`. and that is exactly what `a[0]` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the * when used on a pointer dereferences the pointer. But a[0] is already equivalent to:

```
*(a + 0) // And since the offset is 0, this is equivalent to *a.
```

In other words, dereferencing a pointer to the beginning of the array that has been offset to give you the value of the item at a given 'index'. What YOU wrote is equivalent to:

```
**(a + 0) // And since the offset is 0, this is equivalent to **a.
```

Therefore, you are trying to 'dereference' an int, which won't work. Since * is not a valid unary operator for an int, that fails and causes the error you've seen to appear.

Answer (score 1):

`*a[0]` is the same as `**a`.

Given the declaration `int a[10];`, it should be fairly clear that you are not able to dereference `a` twice.

If you want the first element of the array `a`, then that is simply `a[0]`.

You could also simplify your example to this, and still get the same error:

```
int main() {
    int a[10];
    int b = *a[0];
}
```

Comment: So when accessing an element in an array, it automatically dereferences it?

Comment: @AvP Essentially, yes - it dereferences a pointer that has been offset by the index you specified - I have added an explanantion of that in my answer.